# How to port forward from enp7s0 to localhost:80

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I'm pretty confused and I totally don't understand `iptables`.

I have an nginx server listening on `localhost:80` and I want to access it with my NIC's ip `192.168.29.167:80`. I was following [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables)'s tutorial on setting up the rules.

my:

| type | Interface | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `local` | `lo` | `127.0.0.1` |
| `NIC` `lan` | `enp7s0` | `192.168.29.167` |

I did,

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -o enp7s0 -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -o enp7s0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp7s0 -o lo -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 127.0.0.1 -j SNAT --to-desitnation 127.0.0.1
```

Setting up the `PREROUTING`, `POSTROUTING` and `FORWARD` rules did nothing. I can't access `localhost:80` through `enp7s0`.

(note: I have `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`)

Comment: You should not need forwarding for this.  Simply make the HTTP server listen on the NIC interfaces (or on all interfaces using `*:80`).  If you want to allow that through the firewall, then it is done using a simple `-A  INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Thanks. I know I could listen on all interfaces but I purposefully want to do forwarding, will try this rule.

Comment: Forwarding is not meant for this scenario, though.

Comment: yeah, you're probably right. Just wanted to try out forwarding for fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have an error in the `nat` rules: your interface names seems like incorrect. Better use the `DNAT` based on the destination address, not the input interface name. So, you need only single rule to achieve what you want:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 192.168.29.167 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
```

2. These packets aren't forwarded (transited), but will be input. You should allow this traffic in the `filter/INPUT` chain, not in `filter/FORWARD`. Note, after `DNAT` action the input interface doesn't change (so you should specify `enp7s0` interface, not `lo`). But you can allow any `DNAT` connection with single rule.

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

3. Run the `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.enp7s0.route_localnet=1` to allow to receive from outside the packets, those are addressed to the `127.0.0.1`.
4. Better use `iptables-save -c` commands to list the full rule set with counters. You should see increasing the `nat/PREROUTING` rule counters at least. Also, use the `iptables-apply` to apply new rules. Check the documentation for these utilities.
5. Use the `tcpdump -ni enp7s0 'tcp port 80'` to troubleshoot the traffic from outside.
6. To redirect the local originated traffic you should use these rules

```
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --dst 192.168.29.167 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1
```

Otherwise you cannot to connect to your nginx through 192.168.29.167 address from the server itself.